# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" caused by height of Tablix

Tags: reporting-services

I have an issue with a report causing an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception when run through my web application.  This is, so far, only happening on one QA machine.

I can:

- Run the report locally on my development machine (latest code, same database)
- Run the report through the Reporting Services Web Interface on the QA machine
- Run the report on the QA machine through my web app if I select a format other than PDF/TIFF (e.g. Excel, CSV, HTML, XML all report successfully)

The Reporting Services log on the QA machine looks [like this](http://www.o1solution.com/rsLog.txt) when I get the exception.

I did not find the log helpful so I started whittling the report down to a minimum to find the issue.

What I found confuses me.

Given [the following RDL](http://www.o1solution.com/myReport.txt); I can change the height of Tablix list1 from *3.09444in* to *1in*, deploy the report to the QA server and the report will run successfully.

How in the world could shortening the height of Tablix list1 prevent the exception?

---

**UPDATE**
It's not moving height of the tablix to 1in. It's getting rid of the long decimal on the height.  I changed (*3.09444in* to *3.1in*) and the report ran successfully.  FTR, I did not choose the height 3.09444in...rs chose that for me while I designed the report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed by changing the long decimal on the height of a Tablix from 3.09444in to 3.1in.

I did not choose the height 3.09444in.

The Reporting Services designer chose that for me while I designed the report.

Answer (score 2):

I've experienced this problem a few times.  It typically happens to me when I have a hidden textbox executing some Code.xxx routine and that textbox is located under a table, and the table has some kind of group page break.

It seems that with each page break, the fields hidden under the table are refreshed and sometimes they get a object reference error.

Here's the weird thing - I can typically fix the problem simply by moving all the hidden fields to a location such that their upper left corner is above the table's upper left corner, or to the left of it. It's like the position of the field somehow has some influence on what is refreshed and what is not.

I do not claim to know why it works, it just does.