# Subreport Error: an error occurred during local report processing object reference not set to an instance

Tags: reporting-services

I have a master report that call a sub report and pass one parameter to the sub report, the sub report contain a tablix, the subreport was working fine.
The problem occurred when the the number of records returned from the tablix of the subreport were more than 10 records, it gives an error : "an error occurred during local report processing object reference not set to an instance"

I tried to run the subreport alone by setting a value to the parameter and the report run very well and all the 11 records appeared, the exception only occurred when running the subreport from the master report.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information for us to be able to help you. Tell us what you've tried, help us reproduce this issue, narrow it down a bit.

Comment: I find a solution for the problem, it turned out to be a space problem, the height of my tablix was 0.88381 in, when i changed it to be 1 in and remove the long decimal values, the report worked fine

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165724/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-caused-by-height-of-tabli?rq=1

Comment: Okay, good to hear you fixed it. Voting to mark this question as a duplicate then, making it easy for future visitors to find the solution.